# Check whether there are any updates

Tags: apt

What is the command or script that generates the report that says:

```
xx packages can be updated.
yy of these updates are security updates
```

Comment: Is this homework ? Please update your question with what you have tried and the results.

Comment: @Soren A, No, this is not a homework question. I have AWS instances which generates this report every time I log in. I now have Ubuntu instances created with other cloud providers that do not have this. I can spend some hours learning and tracing the login profile or environment, a task which is not in my primary job focus, or ask the question here. I didn't know there is a question police questioning the purpose of questions. I am very sorry if I have offended you.

Comment: Add that explanation to the question, then maybe someone can help you. Normally when people ask questions like that with no explanation at all, and no effort shown to find a solution, it is lazy students trying to get their assignment fixed easily, But for your "problem" take a look at this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UpdateMotd ... maybe that can point you in the right direction ... or ask AWS support how they do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a regular Ubuntu system, the content is generated by `/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available` using the following command:

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable
```

You can run this command manually without elevated privileges:

```
$ /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable
103 packages can be updated.
77 of these updates are security updates.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable
```